# probability theory notation: sum like vectors?

Tags: probability

When doing probability in higher dimensions, we can say that $X = (X_1, ... , X_n)^T$. If we want to do calculations on $X$, say add a constant to it, do these calculations work out just like normal vectors, i.e. $X + a = (X_1 + a_1, ..., X_n + a_n)^T$ and mean $(\xi_1 + a_1, ... , \xi_n + a_n)^T$? What about variance?

Comment: Supposed $X$ and $Y$ are centered. Then $cov(X+Y,X+Y)=E((X+Y)(X+Y)^T)=cov(X,X)+cov(Y,Y)+E(XY^T+(XY^T)^T)$. If $Y$ is constant, it's just $cov(X,X)$ (linear transformations only scale covariance).

Answer (score 0):

Algebraic manipulations related to multi-dimensional random variables 
(i.e. random matrices, random vectors) do work with the same exact properties
extended to linear algebraic structures. However, distributional properties
related to multivariate random variables can be somewhat tricky. You are 
right to think that for an $n$-dimensional random vector $X$,
$$E[X] = \left[\begin{array}{c} E[X_1] \\ E[X_2] \\ . \\ . \\ . \\
    E[X_n]\end{array}\right],$$
But the variance of a random vector actually generates a variance-covariance
matrix for its inner random variables, i.e.
$$V[X]_{i,j} = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} V[X_i] & i = j \\
      Cov(X_i,X_j) & i \neq j \end{array}\right. .$$
We didn't have this matrix in the one dimensional case because we only had
one (rather than essentially $n$) random variables to deal with.